# How can I get just the audio from a network video in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, video

I have this app that fetches videos from the network and plays them, now I need to play just the audio from those same videos.

Is there a way that allows fetching the audio (any audio extension) alone from a network video file that ends with .mp4?

Please help, thank you.

Comment: may this package can help you. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout